# GWT - Influence naming of obfuscated CSS classes

Tags: css, gwt, obfuscation

I'm using GWT with obfuscated CSS styles (CssResource.style=OBF). For example I get results like `<div class="GI1MGL5PID">`.

Is there any possbility to manage how the style names are generated? I do not want to disable the obfuscation but add some prefix or so to all classes to get something like `<div class="MyApp_GI1MGL5PID">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [`Resources.gwt.xml`](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/f770ceec1c4fbe612a07860f6e546b3cdff5ff9b/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml#L64) property to configure the prefix behavior.

```
<!-- This allows the developer to use shorter obfuscated class names. -->
<!-- Is is valid to extend this property to use a custom name. -->
<define-configuration-property name="CssResource.obfuscationPrefix" is-multi-valued="false" />
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.obfuscationPrefix" value="default" />
```

Property value can be:

- `default`, uses a checksum from all types of your app
- `empty`, this generates the most compact result but it might conflict with outer styles ([example](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/f770ceec1c4fbe612a07860f6e546b3cdff5ff9b/samples/dynatablerf/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/dynatablerf/DynaTableRf.gwt.xml#L32))
- `{string}`, this string is used as a prefix ([example](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/f770ceec1c4fbe612a07860f6e546b3cdff5ff9b/samples/mail/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mail/Mail.gwt.xml#L20))